# How to change the title of bibliography in another language?

Tags: bibliographies

I have used \begin{thebibliography} ; end{thebibliography}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `babel` package, it will be adapted automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts, 2nd edition, 1994.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Replace `catalan` by whatever language you need.

For a non-standard title, use

```
\renewcommand\refname{My non-standard bibliography title}
```

before the bibliography to set the title to *My non-standard bibliography title*.